How can I restart the Civilization Stage?
I saved my game at a bad moment, and now I’m losing because the enemy has every town and 30 planes. I can’t win the game.
Can I restart the game and start with one city again?

No, I don’t want to restart on a new planet; then I wouldn’t ask.
